# Is there any way to "set yourself to away" in Slack automatically?

Tags: slack, automation

I already checked this [link](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/232029467-Automation-apps-for-Slack) and try IFTTT and Zapier, but they only let me post messages to the channels. What I want to do is perform the same action that the comand `/away` does at a given hour, and do the same with `/active`.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IFTTT works great, but its somewhat limited in its functionality towards Slack.

If you want to automatically change your Slack presence you need to code your own Slack app and use the API. You can change your presence with [users.setPresence](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.setPresence).

Btw. You can later connect your Slack App to a custom trigger in IFTTT if you want.